# loading SQL rows into an indexed UITableView

Tags: iphone, sqlite, uitableview

I have about 2000 rows in a SQLite database. Each row has an integer ID and a string value. I'd like to populate them into a UITableView with an alphabetical index like the Contacts app does.

Is it feasible to achieve performance that's as good as the Contacts app without using CoreData, providing I don't need to re-implement everything that CoreData does for you (e.g. caching etc)?

I have tried to implement this using paging with 50 rows per page, and pre-load the next page in another thread when the tableview has scrolled past 25 rows. This works if the scrolling isn't very quick, but still lags when it's scrolled really quickly. I think the step to populate a temporary NSArray of 50 items is taking a long time.

Furthermore, this approach does not work very well for the index for the UITableView because the loading is done sequentially whereas the index skips. I thought about loading the first 10 rows for each index key at initialisation but again, it will be quite slow (populating an array with 260 items).

Any suggestions?

Comment: any particular reason you don't want to use Core Data to do this?

Comment: My app currently uses SQL extensively, this is the only view which I need to populate the whole table. Would it be better to translate this one table to use CoreData? I only need read-only access for all the data so synchronising between the data sources is probably not a concern.

Comment: I would comment the same as @lolcat

Answer (score 0):

It looks like performance for fetching a few thousand rows at once should not be a big deal (You should just be able to pre-fetch them).

I would asynchronously run a SELECT on your table for whatever columns you want (like the index for reference and maybe just the string to be displayed) and throw them into an `NSMutableDictionary` keyed on the index and then reload the table data. The `cellForRowAtIndexPath` `UITableViewDataSource` function would use this dictionary.

If you allow users selecting a row to see details, you can then run a query for the rest of the data for that row upon selection.

Doing the initial fetch asynchronously in `ViewDidLoad` or `ViewWillAppear` will prevent the UI from locking up when the user goes to view the table and in almost all cases the table should already be visible once they actually see the table.

initial fetch(performed on a background thread, followed by the table reloading on the main thread)

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^()
               {
                    //perform your query here
                   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^()
                                  {
                                    [self.tableView reloadData]
                                  });
               });
```

Comment: I've used the code above and it still takes about 1 second to load on the iPhone 4s and 10 seconds on the iPhone 3G. I've got this in place of the "perform your query here" comment above:

    int i = 0;
    while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
        [myDictionary setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", (char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement,0)] forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];
        i++;
    }

As for cellForRowAtIndexPath:

    [cell.textLabel setText:[myDictionary objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row]];

Any idea why it's still slow?

Comment: It's tough to tell from the code formatting but are you running a while loop to fetch sql rows? If you run a separate query for every single row, you will be slowed down by the overhead of each request. You should fetch every row you want in a single query.

Answer (score 0):

i am taking example of A-Z only

take 26 section in table.

there will be 26 query for fetching data 
first for  starting with A 
second is for starting with B
third is for starting with C...... and on upto Z
in cellForRowAtIndexPath().

till the user dont scroll the table it wont fetch data for other alpha bets.

if each From A to Z contain 100 name(text).

still it wont take too much time.

hope you can get idea from here..